# Run shell command in parallel and wait for result

Tags: bash, shell

I want to run `command_a` and `command_b` in parallel, and wait for both of them finishing to start another `command_c`. Is there a simple command/idiom in shell that allows me do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you simply do

```
$ command_a &
$ command_b &
$ wait
```

(the ampersand puts the shell job in the background)

From https://ss64.com/bash/wait.html

> If n is not given, all currently active child processes are waited
>   for, and the return status is zero.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!

Comment: And if you want to avoid the delay caused by typing speed, you can also do `command_a & command_b &`.